# "Run as JUnit" is not appearing in Eclipse Helios?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-3.6

I am trying to run the test case in Eclipse Helios. I have added all the jar files and have written `@Test` also, but I am not getting the "run as JUnit" option in Eclipse; Instead I am getting "run as java applet" and "run as java application".

I have tried changing versions, restarting eclipse, and none of the solutions are working fine... How can I resolve this and get "run as JUnit"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! And please do calm down, clean and concise questions makes it easier for us to get to the point and help ya. :)

Comment: Perhaps this will work: Instead of adding junit as a jar file, tell eclipse to add the junit library to the build path.

Comment: @Thorbjorn have done but its not working

Comment: Try working in a new, empty workspace and follow the instructions on http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-junit.htm.

Comment: And for future readers:  What did you do to fix your existing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have created new workspace and added junit libraries first to build the path and then created test case files got run as junit test case.